# JavaScript Function - Change the color of text

Tags: javascript, colors

I have to make a function called tousVerts ("everythingGreen" in French) that will change the color of all the text I need on the page to green. This text is between tags EM or A in html-code, so I try to get to it with document.getElementByTagName(). One of these tags must pass through the parameters of function and then change the color.

```
var tousVerts = function(elt) {
var tousVerts = document.getElementByTagName (elt);
tousVerts[0];
tousVerts[0].style.color = "green";}
```

I see it has to be something simple but it doesn't work and it seems like I've to use a local i to change the numbers between brackets but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) since it returns multiple elements:

```
var tousVerts = document.getElementsByTagName (elt);
```

Also, `tousVerts[0];` is not needed:

```
var tousVerts = function(elt) {
var tousVerts = document.getElementsByTagName (elt);
tousVerts[0].style.color = "green";}
```

Comment: This will only change the color of the first element to green. You need to loop through all the elements returned by `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: If you look at the code in the question, that's what they want to target.