# JavaScript Function - Change the color of text between tags. 2nd try

Tags: javascript, colors

I'm all new to JavaScript. I already asked for this question but I didn't get a right response. I have to make a function called tousVerts ("everythingGreen" in French) that will change the color of all the text I need on the page to green. This text is between tags EM or A in html-code, so I try to get to it with document.getElementByTagName(). One of these tags must pass through the parameters of function and then change the color.

```
var tousVerts = function(elt) {
var tousVerts = document.getElementsByTagName (elt);
tousVerts[0].style.color = "green";}
```

The function above has to change the color of the 1st element and it doesn't work. I tried:

```
tousVerts(a);
tousVerts("a")
tousVerts(<a>)
```

However I actually need a function that will change all the elements between tags on the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Function - Change the color of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925985/javascript-function-change-the-color-of-text)

Comment: documents.getElementsByTagName is case-sensitive and parameter must be a string. Try tousVerts("A"). Definitely a duplicate YerKar states it.

Comment: Then read the documentation from [your previous question](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) and try the `for` or `forEach`.